# in OSX, any keyboard launcher app that can access application menu options?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, launcher

I'm using AlfredApp, and love how I can launch application with it.
But I'm wondering if anyone know an app that would also list application's menu options.
ie: While in Chrome, I would hit some keyboard shortcut, then type "bookm" and it would show "Bookmark this page", "bookmark manager", etc.

anyone thought of that yet?

Answer (score 1):

You probably knew it already, but you select menu items by searching for their names in the help menu. The default shortcut for focusing it is ⌘? (or ⇧⌘/), but it can be changed in the keyboard preference pane.

[image]

It's not really meant to be a primary way to select menu items in the same way as the Ubuntu HUD. Updating the results is pretty slow, the first result isn't selected automatically, and the effect of highlighting the menu item can be distracting.